# sub-query not accessing parent query alias

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
SELECT *,
`batch`.`batch_id` as `batchId`,
`batch`.`center_id` as `centerId`,
`batch`.`scheme_id` as `schemeId`,
`batch`.`batch_start_date` as `BatchStartDate`,
(SELECT COUNT(`attendance_count`) AS `eligible_for_assessment` FROM 
     (SELECT COUNT(`mark_attendance`) AS `attendance_count` FROM `dailyattendance` 
      WHERE `mark_attendance`="p" AND `scheme_id`=`schemeId` AND `batch_id`=`batchId`
      AND `center_id`=`centerId` GROUP BY `candidate_id`) AS `sfkjsd`
      WHERE `attendance_count` > 6
)
from `batch`
```

in this sub-query it return error, "Unknown column 'schemeId' in 'where clause'". in mysql sub-query accessing parent parameters in 3rd level of sub-query?

```
(SELECT COUNT(`attendance_count`) AS `eligible_for_assessment` FROM 
     (SELECT COUNT(`mark_attendance`) AS `attendance_count` FROM `dailyattendance` 
      WHERE `mark_attendance`="p" AND `scheme_id`=1 AND `batch_id`=2
      AND `center_id`=3 GROUP BY `candidate_id`) AS `sfkjsd`
      WHERE `attendance_count` > 6
)
```

this query return me total count of candidate who is present more than 6 days in a month. i need to pass this "`schemeId`" dynamically from parent select query.

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) from `enrolment` WHERE
`enrolment`.`batch_id`=`batchId` AND `enrolment`.`center_id`=`centerId`
AND `enrolment`.`ew_enrolled_for_scheme`=`schemeId`) as `enrolled_student_count`
```

in this query i am using parent selector `schemeId` and other and it gives me count in result. but if i place another sub-query inside `FROM (SELECT....)` in sub-query like above i mention it will give me error.

Comment: You are doing a mistake here  `scheme_id`=`schemeId` AND `batch_id`=`batchId` on right hand side it should not be `schemeId`. it should be actual value which you are comparing.

Comment: i want to pass schemeId from thi selector `batch.scheme_id as schemeId` to sub-query.

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

`scheme_id`=`schemeId`

should be

`scheme_id`=`batch`.`scheme_id`

and

`batch_id`=`batchId`

should be

`batch_id`=`batch`.`batch_id`

try this code

```
SELECT *,
`batch`.`batch_id` as `batchId`,
`batch`.`center_id` as `centerId`,
`batch`.`scheme_id` as `schemeId`,
`batch`.`batch_start_date` as `BatchStartDate`,
(SELECT COUNT(`attendance_count`) AS `eligible_for_assessment` FROM 
     (SELECT COUNT(`mark_attendance`) AS `attendance_count` FROM `dailyattendance` 
      WHERE `mark_attendance`="p" AND `scheme_id`=`batch`.`scheme_id` AND `batch_id`=`batch`.`batch_id`
      AND `center_id`=`centerId` GROUP BY `candidate_id`) AS `sfkjsd`
      WHERE `attendance_count` > 6
)
from `batch`
```

Comment: without join you can not use batch table it gives error `Unknown column 'batch.scheme_id' in 'where clause'`. if we join batch table, then we don't have any reference from parent selector and result will not return as we want.

Answer (score 0):

'You won't be able to pass "schemeId" as far as I know. Try using another sub-query in the where clause.

```
    SELECT *,
    `batch`.`batch_id` as `batchId`,
    `batch`.`center_id` as `centerId`,
    `batch`.`scheme_id` as `schemeId`,
    `batch`.`batch_start_date` as `BatchStartDate`,
    (SELECT COUNT(`attendance_count`) AS `eligible_for_assessment` 
    FROM 
         (SELECT COUNT(`mark_attendance`) AS `attendance_count` 
          FROM `dailyattendance` a 
          WHERE `mark_attendance`="p" AND `batch_id`=`batchId`
          AND `scheme_id` in (select `scheme_id` from `batch`) 
          AND `center_id`=`centerId` 
          GROUP BY `candidate_id`) AS `sfkjsd`
    WHERE `attendance_count` > 6)
    from `batch`
```

Comment: `batch.batch_id as batchId` this selector i am using as reference in sub-query if i create join in subquery i can't use my selector.

Comment: then try using another sub-query in the where clause Eg. where mark_attendance`="p" AND `batch_id`=`batchId` AND `scheme_id` in (select distinct `scheme_id` from 'batch')

Comment: hope that helps

Comment: can you modify your answer above?

Comment: did that help you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's correct we can not pass the first level of alias in third level of sub-query. You need to select column in third level and then compare into second level.

```
SELECT *,
`batch`.`scheme_id` as `schemeId`,
`batch`.`center_id` as `centerId`,
`batch`.`batch_id` as `batchId`,
(SELECT COUNT(`attendance_count`) AS `eligible_for_assessment` FROM 
     (SELECT COUNT(`mark_attendance`) AS `attendance_count`,
      `center_id` AS `daCenterId`, `batch_id` AS `daBatchId`,
      `scheme_id` AS `daSchemeId` FROM `dailyattendance`
      WHERE `mark_attendance`="p" GROUP BY `candidate_id`)
      AS `sfkjsd`
WHERE `attendance_count` > 6 AND `daCenterId`=`centerId`
AND `daBatchId`=`batchId` AND `daSchemeId`=`schemeId`)
FROM `batch`
```

Hope it helps other!